# period of the curvature and the period of the corresponding curve $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\rho_k}k(s)\mathrm ds\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, plane-curves

The paper " When Is a Periodic Function the Curvature of a Closed Plane Curve?", May 2008 The American Mathematical Monthly 115(5):405-414

The paper says: A Closed Plane Curve, when the (minimum) period of the (signed) curvature and the period of the corresponding curve do not coincide, if and only if

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\rho_k}k(s)\mathrm ds\in\Bbb Q-\Bbb Z$$

where $\rho_k$ is the (minimum) period of the signed curvature.

Please refer to Proposition 2.1 and   the beginning of part 4 of the paper：if  $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\rho_k}k(s)\mathrm ds\in Z$, then in this case the (minimum) period of the curvature and the period of the corresponding curve would coincide if the latter eventually closes up.

---

But the paper dones't prove this. How to show the claim is correct? Thanks

the paper : Wherher take a look at it, doesn't affect the topic here

[When Is a Periodic Function the Curvature of a Closed Plane Curve?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233674174_When_Is_a_Periodic_Function_the_Curvature_of_a_Closed_Plane_Curve)

Comment: You cannot expect us to have access to every paper you come across. Please do not tell us to refer to propositions and pages in the paper.

Comment: @TedShifrin   Thanks    Information has been added

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors? They would be the best people to ask your question to.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the plane curve closes up and has period $\rho$.  Then we know that the (minimum) period $\rho_\kappa$ of the curvature divides evenly into $\rho$, say $\rho = n \rho_k$.  We want to show $\rho = \rho_k$, i.e., $n = 1$.  By equation (2.3) of the paper, it suffices to show $$\int_s^{s+\rho_k} \exp \left( i \int_0^u \kappa(t) \, dt \right) \, du = 0.$$

Let $m = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{\rho_\kappa} \kappa(s) \, ds \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Performing the same algebraic manipulations as in (2.6) and (2.7), we find
$$\begin{equation}
\tag{$\dagger$}
\int_s^{s+\rho} \exp \left(i \int_0^u \kappa(t) \, dt \right) \, du = \left\{ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \exp(2\pi i m j) \right\} \int_s^{s+\rho_\kappa} \exp \left(i \int_0^u \kappa(t) \, dt \right) \, du.
\end{equation}$$

The key point now is that $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \exp(2\pi i m j) \neq 0$.  In fact, the sum is equal to $n$.  However, the left hand side of ($\dagger$) is equal to zero by the assumption that the curve closes up.  Therefore, the other factor on the right is zero, which is what we wanted to show.